# Significance test between two samples when positions matter

Tags: statistical-significance

Let's say that I have two samples:

```
A    B  C    D
100  5  17   12  #<- Method 1
90   2  4    15  #<- Method 2
```

And want to compare to test whether method 1 is different from method 2. However, that observations in the samples are tied together, say `100` and `90` come from the same market `A`. What is the proper way to test this?

I am pretty sure that lumping everything together and doing a t-test or Mann-Whitney U test is not the way to go.

Comment: What do "A", "B", "C", "D" mean?  Could they correspond to factors that have a natural order?  What do the numbers mean?  (Are they counts, measurements of physical quantities, percents, ...?)  How were the numbers obtained--are they the result of a complete census of something, of random samples, of samples of convenience, or something else?

Comment: We can think of "A", "B", "C", "D" as events; they have no order, but values corresponding to those events are paired. I am very sure that paired t-test (as suggested by @Greg Snow) is what I need.

Comment: Exactly how would you apply the paired t-test to these data? It's still not possible to tell whether it would be appropriate or not because you haven't disclosed the (essential) information I mentioned.

Comment: @whuber Let's say we used marketing strategy method 1 in on half of customers in market A, and  marketing strategy method 2 on the other half. Method 1 generated 100 purchases in market A, and method 2 generated 90 purchases in market A, and so on. Does this answer your question?

Comment: Sort of--at least it shows me this is not a matter for a paired t-test! You have 100+90+5+...+15 total results and they are not paired. Although you could (somewhat artificially) pair the *groups* and perform a t-test of the differences 10,3,13,-3 against 0, it would have little power and cannot be recommended. (It reports that $p=0.21,$ which is not significant.) Many people would routinely begin with a *chi-squared* test to see whether any differences between the methods seem to hold. (There is a difference at the 5% level: $\chi^2=8.1$, $p\approx 0.04$ via simulation.)

Comment: @whuber, thank your for your reply, I will read up on those tests, to have proper understanding. Maybe you should post your comment as an answer.

Comment: I hesitate to post an answer because I still do not understand how these numbers were actually obtained. For instance, one of my concerns is that if there were any variation in the amounts of exposure of the individual markets to the two methods, then none of this analysis would produce meaningful results.

Comment: @I have no way of knowing about the amount of exposure for sure, but I don't think the difference is big. What about the if assume that exposure was exactly the same for both groups.

Comment: The problem is that even a little variation, when properly accounted for, will increase the p-value and you're already in a very gray area. I would tentatively conclude that your data are suggestive of a slight superiority of method 1 but if much depends on your conclusion, the evidence may be weak enough to warrant additional data collection.

Comment: Oh, I really have more than 4 observation points, this was just an example (but I don't think this changes the nature of the question). If we assume that variation in exposure is not biased towards any one method over all markets, wouldn't it cancel out as white noise?

Comment: You *hope* it will cancel out. (There may be a lot of value in contemplating why it might not because that could suggest ways to improve your experiments.)  Assuming such cancellation, the noise needs to be accounted for in the testing: that's why the p-value should go up. If you have no control over the exposure variation and cannot measure it, then a rough and ready recourse is to increase the stringency of your criterion for significance.

Comment: McNemara's test would work here if you can reduce this to a 2x2. Otherwise, I'm thinking a logistic regression on the differences with clustered se's and indicator variables for each group on each coefficient. Significant coefficients will indicate a positive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are willing to assume normality of the differences (with your sample size, the assumption will be very important, but if your real data is much larger then the Central Limit Theorem makes this assumption less important) you can use a paired-T test, essentially take the difference between each pair (always the same direction) then do a 1 sample t test on the differences testing if the mean difference is 0.

There are non-parametric tests that will also test pairs and don't require the assumption of normality, but they are going to have very low power given your sample size (the sign test and exact permutation tests will have 0 power for any alpha level less than 0.0625).

Answer (score 1):

Your observations appear to be counts (number of purchases). You would be best to use analyses that relate to that kind of data. A paired t-test won't be particularly suitable for a number of reasons (the variance of the difference isn't constant, for starters)

In this case, a chi-squared test of homogeneity will allow you to test for site-differences.